# Do attributes make your objects heavy

Tags: asp.net-mvc, c#-4.0

Hi I have a class that I will be adding lots of attributes onto its properties. It could be about 3 per property. these attributes will be used by a T4 template to determine how to wrap the object in html. eg I could wrap my textbox in a span and that span in a div and give the div a css class.

will my class be heavy?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, attributes are metadata. They are baked into the assembly at compile time. If there is nothing reading them at runtime you shouldn't worry about performance or your object being *heavy*.

Answer (score 1):

They do make your application heavier in maintenance costs. If you do branch per feature, you will have way more conflicts to resolve than if you went with conventions instead.